# can I set the position of text inside textfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have code like this

```
       Stack(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              autocorrect: false,
              maxLines: 1,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 14,
              left: 0,
              child: Text("Rp"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I know I can set the text in the center using `TextAlign.center`, but now I want to make the text inside textfield at the start + around 24 pt from start

[image]

I can't use `TextAlign.start` since it will overlap the 'Rp' text.

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Prefix or Suffix for the "Rp" text:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefix: ...,
    suffix: ...,)
```

Then you can use `textAlign`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you you can use prefix propery inside Inputdecoration of TextFormField [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) and InputDecoration  [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            autocorrect: false,
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefix: Text('Rp'),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixText: 'Rp',
      ),
    ),
```